# How do I process Russian text in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I need to sort some Russian text file and when I try to read the strings and print them out, they all appear garbled and like boxes. Looks like there is no Russian support for my eclipse. I downloaded Language packs plug in but I can't figure out how to install it. 
Help required please.

```
 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\textfile.txt");
          // Get the object of DataInputStream
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String strLine;
          ArrayList<String> allLines = new ArrayList<String>();
          //Read File Line By Line
          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              allLines.add(strLine);
              System.out.println(strLine);

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you be sure it's an eclipse problem? It could be:

- The encoding of the text file
- The method you used to read the text file (eg: InputStreamReader uses default charset unless you explicitly specify it on the constructor)
- The method you used to store the text file in memory
- The method you used to print the text
- The method you used to view the printed text

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought it could be. 
I've been using InputStreamReader and the the text file is stored in UTF format.

Comment: I've added the code snippet which I have used to read and print the data

Comment: I think you should use `new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8")`, but the problem could lie elsewhere

Comment: The same code can behave differently in *other environment*